# Word Files to Java string : Missing formatting info and showing invalid characters

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to get a `String` of the text contained in a word document. 
The code I've tried using `Apache POI` api is :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
        WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
        String fileData = extractor.getText();
```

`fileData` should contain the data from the word file.

But I'm getting some invalid characters which I would like to eliminate. For example , the following text in word :

```
Project Name    Customer 360

Position        Software Engineer
```

Comes as when printed in java console :

```
Project Name [?]Customer 360[?][?]Position \t [?]Software Engineer
```

Where `[?]` is a question mark symbol in a small box. When I pasted it here , it doesn't come so I just used `[?]` to represent it.

I would like the output to come as this instead :

```
Project Name \t Customer 360 \n Position \t Software Engineer
```

This gives me a info about the tabs and new lines which I really need for processing this text.

I know `tab` and `newline` info are there as I'm getting `\t` and `\n` in some places but in some places its missing.

Comment: I suggest you dump the Unicode character value for each character (by converting it to an `int`) and then look up what that character is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some special fields applying to that text. Most likely it has links, special rules, form fields etc applying to it

If you don't want all of that, you'll want to use the [stripFields(java.lang.String) method on WordExtractor](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/extractor/WordExtractor.html#stripFields%28java.lang.String%29) to remove them leaving just the shown text.

From [the JavaDoc on that method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/extractor/WordExtractor.html#stripFields%28java.lang.String%29):

> Removes any fields (eg macros, page markers etc) from the string.

Your code would then be:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
    HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
    WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
    String rawText = extractor.getText();
    String displayText = extractor.stripFields(rawText);
```